# Eigenvalues of a real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $  A^3=A   $ holds for the real valued matrix $A$, what can we conclude about its eigenvalues?

I thought that if I subtracted  from $A$ on both sides, I would get $ A^3-A=0 $ which factors as $ A(A-1)(A+1)=0 $.
Can I then correctly conclude by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem that since the characteristic polynomial would be $ p(x)= x(x-1)(x+1)=0 \rightarrow p(A)=0?$
Would that prove that the eigenvalues of the matrix would be $\alpha_k=0,1,-1?$
Thank you for any input!

Comment: Since $A$ annihilates $X^3-1$, its minimal polynomial divides $X^3-1$, hence its roots are among $\{0,1,-1\}$. Since the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial share the same set of roots, this means the eigenvalues are among (a subset of) $\{0,1,-1\}$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon This looks like heavy artillery to describe the fact if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $v$ an eigenvector, then $\lambda v = Av = A^3v= \lambda^3 v$ and so $\lambda = \lambda^3 \in\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: Is there a general theorem explaining this that I could refer to for greater understanding?

Comment: @Surb you're right ! I just wanted to write a proof along the lines of what the OP has (wrongfully) written.

Comment: @Surb that should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any matrix $B$ with eigenpair $(\alpha, w)$, i.e. $Bw=\alpha w$, it holds $$B^3w = B^2\alpha w =B\alpha^2w = \alpha^3 w.$$
Hence, if $Av=\lambda v$ with $v\neq 0$ and $A^3 =A$, we obtain
$$\lambda v = Av = A^3v = \lambda^3v,$$
implying that $\lambda = \lambda^3$ and so $\lambda \in\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: Thank you for actually writing out your answer which helped me to better understand.

Comment: @JaeKim You're very welcome. By the way, you might be interested to note that if $Bw=\alpha w$ then $B^kw = \alpha^k w$ for any integer $k$ (of course assuming $B$ is invertible and $\alpha\neq 0$ when $k<0$) and the same still hold for any polynomial, i.e. if $f(x)=\sum_{k=-m_1}^{m_2} c_kx^k$, then $f(B)w = f(\alpha)w$.